# Android Action Bar Action Item Position

Tags: android, action, android-actionbar

Is there a way to center Action Items on the Action Bar?
Something like this [pulse](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cj8n5ozrOj4/TgTVvbehh1I/AAAAAAAABs8/BZTTM9S5ld4/s320/pulse.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The ActionBar doesn't support images in the middle, and I assume Pulse isn't using the real ActionBar.

The ActionBar is a great user interface component - work WITH IT, not against it.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html